# Oracle function or procedure to accept input cursor and return curson

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I would like to write a procedure or function which accepts cursor having employee id and loops through it. If the employee id has any salary in the salary table it should return 0 else the salary. Finally the output be sent as a number or as a cursor. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE
salary_check INTEGER;
CURSOR c1
IS
SELECT employee_id FROM employee_table;
BEGIN
FOR emp_rec in c1
LOOP
  BEGIN
  SELECT salary
  INTO salary_check
  WHERE employee_id = emp_rec.employee_id; --or however you link salary to emp_id
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   salary_check := 0;
  END;

  --do something with the employee salary before looping to the next employee
END LOOP;
END;
```

This should be the bones you would use, can't help you on anything more specific as your details are sparse.